# Depth wise retrieval of nodes from neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a science graph in neo4j which has names of some scientists as nodes and connected to nodes holding laws by relation has_discovered. The laws are then related to their application by relation has_application. I am new to cypher. I want to know what cql query will give me level 1 and level 2 nodes of the scientists nodes. Here level 1 will be the nodes holding laws and level 2 will be nodes holding their applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should probably take care of it, assuming your labels are :Scientist, :Law, and :Application.

```
MATCH (sci:Scientist)-[:has_discovered]->(law:Law)-[:has_application]->(app:Application)
RETURN sci, law, app
```

As long as your :has_discovered and :has_application relationships only connect those types of nodes, you can leave off the :Law and :Application labels (but you'll want to keep the :Scientist label so you begin your pattern match only at :Scientist nodes).

You can use COLLECT() as necessary to group results if you want.